# glViewport, window sizes and clipping

Tags: opengl, opengl-es

I am trying to understand the relationship between the screen and the logic OpenGL uses to decide if a primitive should be rendered, i.e. is it onscreen or not.

For example, suppose you set the viewport larger than the screen (no reason to do this, but for example's sake). OpenGL doesn't "know" the screen size, so it will "draw" points off the screen so long as the orthographic projection places them within the viewport, correct?

But also, if I define a vertex position to be outside the viewport as determined by the projection, does OpenGL include it in rendering?

```
  glViewport(0,0,100,100);
  ApplyOrtho(50,50); // custom ES 2.0 utility to apply 2D orthographic projection
```

Now a vertex of position `(75,75)` would not get rendered by OpenGL, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the logic OpenGL uses to decide if a primitive should be rendered

There is only one piece of logic that OpenGL uses to decide if a primitive should be rendered. If the primitive hasn't been clipped/culled, then the only thing that will stop it from being rasterized is if the user has disabled *all* primitive rasterization with `glEnable(GL_RASTERIZER_DISCARD)`. Otherwise, the OpenGL specification defines that *all* primitives that were not culled as part of clipping will be rasterized.

Now, whether they will produce any *visible effect* is a different question. And since primitives that are off-screen can't produce visible effects (unless you're using image load/store), a conforming OpenGL implementation is free to cull such triangles if it wants. But more likely, it will rasterize them and simply check to see if the fragment falls outside of the window. If it does, it will just discard those fragments.

In general, this should not be something you should be concerned about. Just set a reasonable viewport and you'll be fine.

Comment: For a more technical explanation of this, the term to look for is "pixel ownership test", and that goes even beyond simple "is within window extents" tests. For example a window occluding your rendering window may also fail the fragments below it to fail the window ownership test and OpenGL will discard those fragments then. This is one of the reasons you should always use a proper off-screen buffer if rendering to a texture or an image you want to store away.

Comment: @datenwolf: The pixel ownership test (and I looked it up while I was writing this answer) doesn't apply to parts of the viewport that are outside of the window. It only applies to OS-specific conditions of non-visibility of parts of a window (the window is partially off-screen, or another window is partially obscuring the window, etc). Note that when rendering to an FBO, all fragments *pass* the pixel ownership test.

Comment: As far as I understand that the codepath that's reponsible for discarding fragments of viewports extending outside of the window limits shares a lot with the pixel ownership test code.